# React-Redux API Get request action does not execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

Hello I am currently using React-Redux in order to get information from my Flask API and display the json on the website, The API is working perfectly but the action that is called never seems to execute? I am very new to redux so I fear I have missed something? my reducer displays infomation when supplied dummy data but the action wont seem to execute to get the data? my default data in my action is not even displayed?

**Dashaction.js**

```
import axios from "axios";


export function loadyield(){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        return axios.get("localhost:5000/getallyield"), then ((response) => {
            dispatch(updateyield(response.json));
        })
    }
}


export function updateyield(total){
    return{
        type:"UPDATE_YIELD",
        total: total
    }
}
```

**DashReducer.js**

```
let defaultState={
    total: "No Data"
}

const DashReducer=(state=defaultState,action) =>{
    if(action.type==="UPDATE_YIELD"){
        return{
            ...state,
            total:action.total
            }
        } else{
            return{
                ...state
            }
        }
    }
export default DashReducer;
```

**DashContainer.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import dashReducer from '../store/reducers/dashReducer';


class DashContent extends Component {

    render () {
        return(

        <div>
        <h3> Total</h3>
        <p>{this.props.total}</p>
        </div>
        );
    }

}
function mapStatetoProps(state) {
    return state
    };

export default connect(mapStatetoProps) (DashContent);
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import DashContent from '../containers/dashboardcontainer'
import { Layout, Breadcrumb } from 'antd';
const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content, } = Layout;



class Dashboard extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
        <div className ="dashboard container">
            <DashContent>
            </DashContent>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import rootReducer from './components/store/reducers/routeReducer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store = {store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any advice would be great ! :)

Comment: Where are you calling your action? I don't even see it in `connect`?

Comment: apologies i added the comment before the I saw the answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just need to actually use it.

In `DashContainer`:

1. Import it:

```js
import { loadyield } from './components/store/actions/Dashaction' 
// or whatever the correct path is
```

2. Bind it to dispatch by passing it to `connect` ([docs on `mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object)):

```js
export default connect(mapStatetoProps, {loadyield})(DashContent);
```

2. Call it when `DashContainer` mounts:

```js
class Dashboard extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadyield();
  }

  render(){
      ...
```

Comment: I seem to get the error :  ×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at dashboardcontainer.js:12)
    in DashContent (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Dashboard.js:15)
    in div (at Dashboard.js:14)
    in Dashboard (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:16) I will accept the answer anyway as it does solve the question at hand. This issue may require a new post

Comment: Yeah I would do some logging inside your actions. It seems like the `total` might contain a promise instead of the value you expect, but I'm not exactly sure. Logging the value of `this.props.total` might be insightful too.