# Uncaught Promise when rendering redux action with axois

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi I am using redux to do some API calls when trying to render the json response. I am trying to log the responses to work out what is happening but even that is not working?

**dashaction.js**

```
export function updateyield(total){
    return{
        type:"UPDATE_YIELD",
        total: total
    }
}

export function loadyield(){
    return(dispatch)=>{
        return axios.get("localhost:5000/getallyield").then ((response) => {
            dispatch(updateyield(response.data));
            let res = response.data;
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    }
}
```

this is rendered in **DashContent**

```
class DashContent extends Component {

    render () {
        return(

        <div>
        {this.props.loadyield()}
        <h3> Yield</h3>
        <ul>{this.props.total}</ul>
        </div>
        );
    }

}
function mapStatetoProps(state) {
    return state
    };

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, {loadyield}) (DashContent);
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at dashboardcontainer.js:12)
    in DashContent (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Dashboard.js:15)
    in div (at Dashboard.js:14)
    in Dashboard (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:16)
    in Switch (at App.js:15)
    in div (at App.js:13)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:12)
    in App (at src/index.js:13)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:13)
```

Is this an error with my request? or how I am rendering the response? from my API log nothing seems to have been recieved? apologies if I have not provided enough infomation

Comment: Why did you put the action call in JSX instead of in the lifecycle method like in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59867220/9381601)?

Comment: haha I did i was making some changes/debugging another issue and mistakenly put it back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is that you are calling the `loadyield()` function in the returned JSX tag

You can load the data once the component mounts. You can do this by adding a `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method. So your **DashContent** Would look something like this.

```
class DashContent extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.loadyield();
    }
    render () {
        return(
        <div>
            <h3> Yield</h3>
            <ul>{this.props.total}</ul>
        </div>
        );
    }

}

function mapStatetoProps(state) {
    return state
};

export default connect(mapStatetoProps, {loadyield}) (DashContent);
```

Alternatively you can use `componentWillRecieveProps` (this lifecycle method has been deprecated. It can be replaced like [this](https://hackernoon.com/replacing-componentwillreceiveprops-with-getderivedstatefromprops-c3956f7ce607)) or simply have a refresh button which dispatches the action to update the yield.

Comment: `componentWillRecieveProps` has been [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), but otherwise your answer is correct.

Comment: perfect thank you! I have another question it may warrant another post but my component renders as undefined then after I am able to get a log of successful request in my console but nothing loads, is the component mounting before the request has arrived?

Comment: It probably has to do with `componentDidMount` lifecycle. It only executes once (the first time the component is mounted onto the DOM). You can check out the replacement for `componentWillRecieveProps` link in my answer

Comment: ahhh i think it is because i am using mapStatetoprops not mapDispatchtoprops ?

Comment: dont think so `mapDispatchToProps` is simply an object. You pass `{ loadyield }` to connect as `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: you can use `componentWillRecieveProps` for development and then for deploying version you can refactor it to the new standards.